# about complete binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

is this possible that a node in the complete binary tree has just one child?
thanks

Can this be a complete binary tree?

```
        23
       /  \
      12  15
     /  \   
    9   11 
   / \    \
  10  5    13
```

Comment: No, this is not a complete binary tree. The nodes must be aligned from left to right. If the 13 node was a left child instead of a right, then your binary tree will be complete.

Comment: aha also it does not matter that for one node a left child is greater than right child?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter.

Comment: @ Petar: but in other answers were written that all level should be full it means that level#3 is not also full except from your reason

Comment: @matin1234 You are right. I am absent-minded right now and just didn't see that level#3 is not full. I am sorry for that.

Comment: @ Petar: no problem :) I have a question that binary tree is an ordered tree so what is the order in my example? if I make it complete tree

Comment: An ordered binary tree is called binary search tree(BST). For every node, all nodes in the left subtree must be less or equal (<=) to the node and all nodes in the right subtree must be greater(>) than it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: aha and for example heap is a nearly full binary tree not the ordered one,yes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap. In the heap every node value must be greater or equal to all of its children.

Answer (score 6):

OK, first to make the difference between a perfect and a complete binary tree. In a perfect binary tree every node has two children(if not a leaf) or no children(if a leaf). So a perfect binary tree of level `N` has totally `2^(N + 1) - 1` nodes. But if we talk about complete binary tree - this means every level, except the last is full, and the last level may not be full. Also in a complete binary tree, the last level nodes must be filled from left to right.

So if you talk about perfect binary tree, it is not possible. But if you mean the complete binary tree, it is possible to have only one child.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is possible:

```
     *
    / \
   /   \
  *     x
 / \   / 
*   * *
```

this is a

> binary tree in which
>   every level, except possibly the last,
>   is completely filled, and all nodes
>   are as far left as possible

And node `x` has just one child.

Comment: Depends on the definition, and I’d like to have a source for yours, but yes, this *is* a sensible definition which allows this. +1

Comment: I took the definition from vlood's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Citing Wikipedia:

> A complete binary tree is a binary
>   tree in which every level, except
>   possibly the last, is completely
>   filled, and all nodes are as far left
>   as possible.

Which means no.

Comment: “except …” followed by “no” is a non sequitur, i.e. a logical fallacy.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Which means Yes"?

Comment: Which means 'no' => the provided example is not a complete binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

From the other answers:

> A complete binary tree is a binary tree in which **every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled**, and all nodes are as far left as possible.

```
        23
       /  \
      12  15
     /  \   
    9   11     <- not the last level, but not completely filled!
   / \    \
  10  5    13  <- last level: not completely filled, but that's okay
```

So this example tree is not complete, according to this definition.